# Oracle MERGE, AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION and Triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Here is my problem:

A MERGE statement I am trying to run is encountering error. So - in order to find the culprit rows - I have created two triggers ( one for UPDATE and other for INSERT )

Since the MERGE statement will fail - I have added autonomous transaction to the trigger so that the culprit record is captured whether the transaction fails or succeeds.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_ins
before insert on
    cust
referencing old as old
new as new
for each row
declare
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin

insert into cust_audit
(
      CUST_ID
    )
    values
    (
       :new.CUST_ID
    );
    commit;
 end;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_upd
before UPDATE on
    cust
referencing old as old
new as new
for each row
declare
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin

insert into cust_audit
(
      CUST_ID
    )
    values
    (
       :new.CUST_ID
    );
    commit;
 end;
```

The triggers work when the MERGE succeeds, but when it fails - there are no rows in the *AUDIT table.

Any idea ?

Comment: "is encountering error" - would be helpful if you listed the error, no?

Comment: Have you tried adding an exception block inside of the trigger? Possibly one with a table insert?

Comment: What is the type of cust id . Make it as a varchar or clob if there is chance of longer value and verify